# Making a specific label in a repeater visible after binding

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to make a specific label in my repeater visible after binding.
I don't want all the labels of every items in the repeater to be visible. Just the one where I click the button.
When I click the button update I'm updating the information for my tourney item in my DB then I want to show a label to say the change was a success but only for the item I updated.

Here's the code behind. The [...] is where I do the update in the DB

```
protected void repeatTourney_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)  
           {  
               if (e.CommandName == "btnUpdate_Click")  
               {  
                   [...]
                   Label lblSuccess= (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblUpdateSuccess");
                    bindRepeater(ddlEvents.Text);
                    lblSuccess.Visible = true;
               }
           }
```

Here's the aspx. The [...] is the textboxes and other stuff that contains info for my DB item.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeatTourney" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeatTourney_ItemDataBound"
                    OnItemCommand="repeatTourney_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="form">
           [...]
            <asp:Label ID="lblUpdateSuccess" runat="server" Text="Update success" Visible="false" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="button" CommandName="btnUpdate_Click" />
            [...]
        </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

In the end it should look like this

```
Item
 Info
 BtnUpdate
 lblSuccess.Visible = false

Item
 Info
 BtnUpdate <== Clicked
 lblSuccess.Visible = true
```

Thank you for any help provided.

Edit : Here's my bindRepeater code

```
 private void bindRepeater(string name)
        {
            List<Tourney> list = TourneyDAL.GetByNameEvent(name);
            [...]
            repeatTournois.DataSource = list;
            repeatTournois.DataBind();
            [...]
        }
```

Edit 2 :
Thank you for the idea of an ID to tell which one need to be visible after the binding.

Worked just fine. :)

Here my new code

```
private void bindRepeater(string name, int index)
    {
        List<Tourney> list = TourneyDAL.GetByNameEvent(name);
        [...]
        repeatTourney.DataSource = list;
        repeatTourney.DataBind();
        [...]
        if (index != 0)
        {
            Label lblReussie = (Label)repeatTourney.Items[index].FindControl("lblUpdateSuccess");
            lblSuccess.Visible = true;
        }

protected void repeatTourney_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)  
       {  
           if (e.CommandName == "btnUpdate_Click")  
           {  
               [...]
               Label lblSuccess= (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblUpdateSuccess");
                bindRepeater(ddlEvenements.Text, e.Item.ItemIndex);
                lblSuccess.Visible = true;
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: You haven't said what's going wrong, do you get an exception? You could use `ItemDataBound` to set the visibility. But therefore you have to store which index/id you have updated last, e.g in a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said what's going wrong, do you get an exception?

You could use `ItemDataBound` to set the visibility. But therefore you have to store which index/id you have updated last, e.g in a field:

```
protected void repeatTourney_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (e.CommandName == "btnUpdate_Click")  
    {  
        updatedID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        bindRepeater(ddlEvents.Text);
    }
}


private int? updatedID = null;

protected void repeatTourney_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var tourney = (Tourney) e.Item.DataItem;
        Label lblUpdateSuccess = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblUpdateSuccess");
        lblUpdateSuccess.Visible = updatedID.HasValue && tourney.Id == updatedID.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't do exactly that but it worked just fine with an ID. Thank you. :)